# Is it possible to modify defined getter function?

Tags: javascript, wechat

Working on a performance reviewing tool on wechat mini apps platform (javascript + native hybrid based on wechat app), I am trying to inject codes into its prototypes, for example the `wx.request` function.

This is how you would use a `wx.request` function:

```
wx.request({
  url: 'test.php',
  data: {
     x: '' ,
     y: ''
  },
  header: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res.data)
  }
})
```

So in order to know how long the request has taken without manually writing adding all the anchors, I tried to inject code by:

```
var owxrequest = wx.request
wx.request = function() {
  console.log('test', Date.now())
  return owxrequest.apply(owxrequest, arguments)
}
```

This failed and I got an `Cannot set property "prop" of #<Object> which has only a getter` error.

So I realized the the object must have been defined similar to:

```
wx = {
  request: get function(){
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

So I tried:

```
var owxrequest = wx.request
Object.defineProperty(wx, 'request', {
  get: function() {
    console.log('test', Date.now())
    return owxrequest.apply(owxrequest, arguments)
  }
})
```

This failed with an error (`request: fail parameter error: parameter.url should be String instead of Undefined`). Then I tried:

```
var owxrequest = wx.request
Object.defineProperty(wx, 'request', {
  set: function() {
    console.log('test', Date.now())
    return owxrequest.apply(owxrequest, arguments)
  }
})
```

This wouldn't throw an error but it also has no effect when calling `wx.request()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this by re-define the getter. The point is: the re-defined getter should return a function object, as `wx.request` is a function:

```
Object.defineProperty(wx, 'request', {
  get: function() {
    return function() {
      //...
    };
  }
});
```

*Why I get the error: `request: fail parameter error: parameter.url should be String instead of Undefined`?*

You are trying to access the `arguments` of the getter itself (the `arguments` of function in `get: function(){...}`). This `arguments` is an empty object and it can be verified by `console.log()` statement. As it is empty, `arguments.url` is undefined, that's why wx complains about the parameter.

Here is an working example:

```
let wx = {
  get request(){
    return function() {
      console.log(10);
      return 88;
    };
  }
};

let oldF = wx.request;

Object.defineProperty(wx, 'request', {
  get: function() {
    return function() {
      console.log(new Date());
      return oldF.apply(wx, arguments);
    };
  }
});

console.log(wx.request());
```

The above code would print:

```
2017-08-28T06:14:15.583Z // timestamp
10
88
```

Comment: This is how you define a getter, I see!

Comment: @AeroWang I've also added the explanation for the error mentioned in question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You could just shadowing the `request` function.
Simple example:

Shadowing the getter:

```js
// original getter latest
let base = {
  num: 1,
  get latest() {
    return this.num;
  }
}
console.log(base.latest);

// shadowing getter latest
Object.defineProperty(base, 'latest', {
  get: function() {
    return this.num + 1;
  }
});

console.log(base.latest);
```

Simple shadowing a object property

```js
// your original object
let base = {
    request(){
        console.log('request original');
    }
};

base.request()


base.request = () => {
    console.log('request new implementation');
};
 
// now shadow the original request implementation
base.request()
```

Comment: This would work if I don't care about preserving the original `wx.request` function, but here I do need to preserve it (having no access to the original code so I don't know the secret keys and encryption algorithms to complete the request).

Comment: thanks for clarification was not clear for me that you do not have access to the original code. In this case I could suggest to look at aspect oriented programming, which could be handful to trace time for execution of your code.